# Disable or Remove Icon for a User App in Gnome Classic

Tags: gnome, icons, motif

I have a window from an app that needs to be on top of the window stack under any and all circumstances. The app is coded in Motif. In the Motif Window Manager (MWM), this is done by removing the minimize icon and functionality, which I’ve done. The problem is that Gnome creates an icon for this window anyway, and if you click on that icon it can minimize the window. Is there any way I can either prevent that icon from displaying or disable it?

Comment: You probably should work with a modal dialog instead of a regular window then.

Comment: Unfortunately you still need the be able to interact with other windows app-wise and system-wise. Modal dialogs, by definition, don't allow that.